# Definite integral. My answer is different from Wolfram alphas. Why?

Tags: definite-integrals

I am trying to solve this definite integral:

$$\int_0^1 ( x^{10} + 10^{x} )$$

$$ \left[ \frac{x^{11}}{11} + \frac{10^x}{\ln 10} \right ]_0^1$$

$$ \frac{1}{11} + \frac{10}{\ln{10}} - 1$$

But wolfram alpha says this:

[image]

How do I unite the two?

Comment: On the third line, the last term should be 1/ ln10.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have mistakenly taken $10^0$ as $0$.

Comment: Why do they use log(10) instead of ln(10)?

Comment: $\log x$ means $\log_e x$.

Comment: @Jwan622:  You missed the point.  When you evaluate $\frac {10^x}{\log 10}$ at $x=0$ you get $\frac 1{\log 10}$, not $1$  You are assuming $\log$ is $\log_{10}$ but it is not.  It is the natural log.

Answer (score 1):

You just substituted the value wrong.

\begin{align}
\left. \frac{x^{11}}{11} + \frac{10^x}{\ln 10} \right|_0^1 &= \frac{1-0}{11} + \frac{10^1-10^0}{\ln 10}\\
&= \frac{1}{11}+\frac{9}{\ln 10}
\end{align}

Comment: Why does wolfram use log 10 instead of ln 10? Isn't this a totally different number?

Comment: if you type $\log(e)$ in WA, it gets evaluated to $1$, WA use $e$ as the base for log.